# How to connect simulated robot in rviz to real robot?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have learned basics of ros and moveit package but i don't know how to link between simulated robot and physicle robot can any one tell me how to make this process

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239601/how-to-connect-simulated-robot-in-rviz-to-real-robot-?/) by [FaredEtman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27498/faredetman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is just a visualisation tool; it does not simulate anything. The simulator you are most likely running is gazebo and rviz is just visualising the data gazebo produces. To run rviz and moveit connected to the robot, you have to make sure that it communicates with the same roscore as the robot drivers.

- Start roscore on the robot
- Start the hardware drivers of the robot
- Set up your remote machine to communicate with the robot: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines
- Start rviz on that remote machine

I hope that helps as a rough guideline. If you need more help, please give a more detailed description of your system set-up and the robot you use.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1